# E/CameraSource: Failed to start recording, received error: Function not implemented (-38)

Tags: android, mediarecorder, video-recording

I am calling prepare method on MediaRecorder From a thread in a service to record video.

```
 private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (prepareMediaRecorder()) {
                mediaRecorder.start();
            } else {
                releaseMediaRecorder();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            SpyCameraUtility.showToast(SecretRecordingApplication.getAppState(), "Camera is used by other application , can't record.");
            FirebaseCrash.report(e);
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    finishService();
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

> 

```
  private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    if (recordingType == Constants.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO || recordingType == Constants.MEDIA_TYPE_INSTANT) {
        if (chooseCamera() == null)
            return false;
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewTexture(textureView.getSurfaceTexture());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Surface texture is unavailable or unsuitable" + e.getMessage());
            FirebaseCrash.report(e);
            return false;
        }
        mCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(rotation);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(getCamcorderProfile());
        recordingFilePath = SpyCameraUtility.openFileForStorage(this, 0, recordedFileInfo).getAbsolutePath();
        mediaRecorder
                .setOutputFile(recordingFilePath);// video


    } else if (recordingType == Constants.MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        recordingFilePath = SpyCameraUtility.openFileForStorage(this, 1, recordedFileInfo).getAbsolutePath();
        mediaRecorder
                .setOutputFile(recordingFilePath);// audio



    }
    Intent i = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_START_SERVICE);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        showUnknownError(e);
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        showUnknownError(e);
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        showUnknownError(e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Sometimes it gives me following error

```
10-03 21:22:43.738 3099-12598/? E/CameraClient: mSurface or mPreviewWindow must be set before startRecordingMode.
```

10-03 21:22:43.738 3099-12598/? E/CameraSource: Failed to start recording, received error: Function not implemented (-38)
10-03 21:22:43.738 3099-3780/? D/MPEG4Writer: Stopping writer thread
10-03 21:22:43.748 3099-12597/? D/MPEG4Writer: 0 chunks are written in the last batch
10-03 21:22:43.748 3099-3780/? D/MPEG4Writer: Writer thread stopped
10-03 21:22:43.748 3099-3780/? D/MPEG4Writer: Video track stopping
10-03 21:22:43.748 3099-3780/? E/MPEG4Writer: Stop() called but track is not started
10-03 21:22:43.748 3099-3780/? D/MPEG4Writer: Audio track stopping
10-03 21:22:43.748 3099-3780/? E/MPEG4Writer: Stop() called but track is not started

This error is too frequent almost 7/10. I couldnot get much on stackoverflow related to this error.
Can someone help me in fixing above.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which device was that?

Comment: @AlexCohn  I think it was samsung galaxy s6 at that time .. can't exactly recall right now .

Comment: Thanks, such error has been reported on S6 and some other Galaxy devices